# AWS Elastic Beanstalk CLI "eb ssh" send command to instance when opening it via itermocil

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, iterm

```
eb ssh -n 1
```

would connect to the currently selected env and instance 1 in the list of instances.

is it somehow possible to execute a command once the shell is open?
I'm using itermocil and would like to automatically execute a tail -

Right now my config looks like this:

```
windows:
  - name: general
    root: ~/Documents/LocalProjects/project
    layout: tiled
    panes:
      - commands:
         - cd web
         - eb ssh -n 1
      - commands:
         - cd worker
         - eb ssh -n 1
```

Comment: Have your tried using `ForceCommand` in your `ssh_config`, or just using a user level `.ssh/rc` file?

Comment: I don't think that would work - its EB not EC2, they are leveraging EC2 instances but any instance can disappear at any moment - also that force command would then essentially be for all ssh connections...

Comment: Ahh, your right, transient instance... well you could always use iTerm's AppleScript interface to `write text` to that window's session by using `osascript` to execute the `eb shh -n 1` command first and than use `write text`

Answer (score 2):

It seems it's possible with newer version of eb cli

```
➜  eb --version
EB CLI 3.10.2 (Python 2.7.1)

➜  eb ssh --command "pwd"
INFO: Running ssh -i /Users/xxx/.ssh/xxx ec2-user@0.1.2.3 pwd
/home/ec2-user
```

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb3-ssh.html